# Appium and Compose NoSuchMethodError crash

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, accessibility, semantics

Upgraded to the lastest version of compose, then oversuddenly i get this crash on the app. Not sure if this is caused by Appium or the app itself:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No super method getCurrentSemanticsNodes()Ljava/util/Map; in class Landroidx/compose/ui/platform/AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat' appears in /data/app/~~==/com.xxxx.xxxx-p-kmK94qiia5fKufOVHsFg==/base.apk!classes10.dex)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.performActionHelper(Unknown Source:16)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.access$performActionHelper(AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.android.kt:132)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat$MyNodeProvider.performAction(AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.android.kt:3266)
at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.performAccessibilityActionUiThread(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:758)
at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.access$600(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:74)
at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$PrivateHandler.handleMessage(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1550)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```